# OpenGL- JOGL colors

Tags: java, opengl, graphics

I'm having some problems with the simple 2D game in OpenGL in JOGL I'm making. I'm mapping some textures in this game. When I want render some graphic object (f.e Guads) with some color (no texture), I use procedure `glColor3d(x,x,x)`. The object get this color, but all other textures are shaded with this color. I want to set color only for one graphics object, but this procedure sets color shade for all objects rendered aftwerwards. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already noticed, `glColor3*` changes also the color for textures. There are two ways to solve your problem:

1. Call `glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` before rendering textured objects
2. Use `glPushAttrib()`/`glPopAttrib()` pair for storing drawing properties.

Anyway, all of the above functions are already deprecated - you might want to look on tutorial about new OpenGL.

Comment: Because it's your first question here, I want to humbly tell you that there're *upvote* and *accept* options ;)

Comment: I have poor english, I understood that I should clicked on accept answer. Ok? My voting required 15 reputations and therefore I can not vote up already...

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the needed rep for upvote. Yeah, i meant that if you think my answer is complete and you find it satisfying, you should accept it. Thanks ;)